# OSX 10.9.2 Pylab suddenly not importing

Tags: python, macos, scipy, osx-mavericks

I recently wanted to mess around with Vpython and followed the instructions on this site: http://vpython.org/contents/download_mac.html

Before this point, I had python up and running on my laptop and installed libraries using macports. Since following the installation steps described on the Vpython page, I can no longer use any of my scipy related libraries. For example, when importing numpy it just says

```
ImportError: No module named pylab
```

Also, when looking in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` scipy isn't present, even though `macports` says `py27-scipy` is installed (and I've tried reinstalling).
I'm guessing the python install (which I naively thought was standalone) that I preformed when installing Vpython has messed up a path or something and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your shell `PATH` has been modified so that another Python is being found before the MacPorts one, the one that has Pylab installed to it.  Try typing `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`, assuming you've used the default MacPorts install prefix.

MacPorts Pythons do not install into `/Library/Python` or `/Library/Frameworks`.

Comment: Typing that did work, thanks for the help. I think I have the macports version working as my default python now. Thanks for the help!